# Remove milliseconds after converting, avg and casting

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

Ok. After researching, researching and a little more researching, I've gotten this far and I need help on my last step.

```
SELECT Cast(DateAdd( ss,AVG(DateDiff( ss, '00:00:00', (A.ReceivedWhen - A.CallStartWhen))), '00:00:00' )  as time) as 'avg duration'
```

I have gotten the difference between my ReceivedWhen and CallStartWhen, Averaged it and Grouped it. No problem.

My 'avg duration' is correct except it has the milliseconds included

> 00:01:43.0000000

How can I remove my milliseconds?

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: The type? MS SQL 2017 if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of the expression is `time` which per se has no format. It's up to the client to format it for display. So the answer could be, that you should handle that in your client.

However [`time`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) can optionally have the fractional second scale specified. The default, if omitted, is `7` -- 100ns. You could use `0`, if you don't want any fractional seconds.

```
...
Cast(DateAdd( ss,AVG(DateDiff( ss, '00:00:00', (A.ReceivedWhen - A.CallStartWhen))), '00:00:00' )  as time(0)) as 'avg duration'
...
```

You could also wish to transform it to `varchar` and apply a style to it. Use [`convert()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) to do so. From the descriptions in the section ["Date and Time Styles"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles), `8` -- "hh:mi:ss" -- seems to be a what you want.

```
...
convert(varchar, Cast(DateAdd( ss,AVG(DateDiff( ss, '00:00:00', (A.ReceivedWhen - A.CallStartWhen))), '00:00:00' )  as time), 8) as 'avg duration'
...
```

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks @sticky-bit